# Solving a line integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, line-integrals

A vector field $\overrightarrow{E}=7x^2\hat{e}_x +3y\hat{e}_y-2xz\hat{e}_z$

Evaluate the line integral I$=\int_{c} \overrightarrow{E}\bullet d\overrightarrow{I}$ where the contour C is the straight line from the point (0,0,0) to (1,2,0)

I was wondering if we are allowed to split the intergral up, so for example

$I= \int_{0}^{1} 7x^2 dx + \int_{0}^{2} 3yzdx$

So do the line integral from (0,0,0) to (1,0,0) in the first integral then (1,0,0) to (1,2,0).

or is there an easier method.

Comment: In general, line integrals along different paths between the same endpoints need not be the same. However, if we consider the field $\boldsymbol E$ in the $xy$-plane, then $\phi(x, y) = 7 x^3/3 + 3 y^2/2$ is a potential for $\boldsymbol E$, hence the integral along any path in the $xy$-plane with endpoints $A$ and $B$ is $\phi(B) - \phi(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

You could choose the path $(0,0,0)$ to $(1,0,0)$ to $(1,2,0)$. Please note that at each step you have only one of $x, y, z$ change.

$\vec{E}=7x^2 \, \hat{x} +3y \, \hat{y}-2xz \, \hat{z}$

So, $ \displaystyle \int_{c} \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{I} = \int_0^1 7x^2 \, dx + \int_0^2 3y \, dy$

Or you can use the parameterized equation of line between $(0,0,0)$ to $(1,2,0)$.

$ \displaystyle \frac{x-0}{1-0} = \frac{y-0}{2-0} = \frac{z-0}{0-0} = t \implies x = t, y = 2t, z =0$.

$dx = dt, dy = 2dt$.

When $(0,0,0), t = 0$; when $(1,2,0), t = 1$.

So, $ \displaystyle \int_{c} \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{I} = \int_0^1 7t^2 \, dt +  3(2t)(2dt) = \int_0^1 (7t^2 +  12t) dt = [\frac{7t^3}{3}+6t^2]_0^1 = \frac{25}{3}$

**EDIT:** I earlier missed to call out that if the vector field is not conservative, we would have to choose the path that is given as line integral would not be path independent. However in this specific case, choosing the path $C_1$ from $(0, 0, 0)$ to $(1, 0, 0)$ to $(1, 2, 0)$ works. The direction vector from $(0, 0, 0)$ to $(1, 2, 0)$ is in $XY$ plane (no $z$ component) and if we take only $XY$ component of our vector field ($7x^2, 3y$), it is conservative ( $\nabla (\frac{7}{3}x^3, \frac{3}{2}y^2)$). Our chosen path $C_1$ also ensures that we are only moving in $XY$ plane.

Comment: The force field is not conservative, so you cannot just choose your favorite path.

Comment: I'd say the edited answer is less correct than the original one. The old one just didn't explain why integrating along the polyline $C_1 = [(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 2, 0)]$ gives the correct result, the new one seems to imply that integrating along $C_1$ gives a wrong result.

Comment: @Maxim I was trying to answer in general. In this case, it does not give wrong result as the alternate chosen path is also in XY plane. I have clarified now.